# Rendering JSON using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, instagram

We have a link at the end of which is a lot of JSON. How can we turn the contents of the link into a string, and then render that JSON as objects?

EDIT
We have decided to use other methods, but thank you for your help. We have accepted the answer we found most useful

Comment: What have you tried?  What is the JSON like?  Are you having trouble rendering the JSON, or using the API to get the JSON?

Comment: When you are try to ask something please post it clearly we cant suggest you the correct answer with this two line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like that to show complex JSON to a user, **with indent**:

```
var pre = document.createElement("pre");
var textNode = document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(someObject, null, 4));
pre.appendChild(textNode);
document.body.appendChild(pre);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the only answer I can give with the amount of info you provided

```
document.body.innerHTML = jsonData.toString();
```

EDIT: alternativly if its a regular JS object you would need to do:

```
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I agree that the question is terribly vague, but the result of calling `.toString()` on a typical object is the string `[object Object]` and not any interesting rendering of a data structure.

Comment: yes, I have added another possibility to my Answer if its an actual object :)

Answer (score 0):

Possible Duplicate of :[Rendering json using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787596/rendering-json-using-jquery).

1. or try  `var myJSONObject = JSON.parse(myJSONString);`
2. `var jsonString = JSON.stringify(myJsonObject);`

Comment: you forgot to add the actual rendering part :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,,

```
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(jsondata);
```

This may help you